# Kafka non-recoverable lag

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a number of kafka topics with a significant lag for a particular consumer group.  It seems that new messages can be posted to the topic and will be picked up by members of the consumer group, yet the lag will remain.  Restarting the services which consume from the topic has no effect on the lag.  Attempts to consume the messages using the kafka-console-consumer have also been unsuccessful.

Why would a topic have lag like this? By lag, I am referring to the delta between the current offset, and latest offset (in theory the read/committed messages). The topics in question have 50 partitions, but generally only one consumer reading from all partitions

Describing one of the topics returns a result like this:

```
kafka-consumer-groups --command-config ./client-ssl.properties --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group error-handler --describe

error.foo.bar                    41         9               1126            1117            consumer-63-5b0fd4f0-5289-490f-8c6a-d2b336c4d4c4 /10.13.90.3   consumer-63
error.foo.bar                    17         8               1126            1118            consumer-63-5b0fd4f0-5289-490f-8c6a-d2b336c4d4c4 /10.13.90.3   consumer-63
error.foo.bar                    8          8               1125            1117            consumer-63-5b0fd4f0-5289-490f-8c6a-d2b336c4d4c4 /10.13.90.3   consumer-63
error.foo.bar                    1          9               1127            1118            consumer-63-5b0fd4f0-5289-490f-8c6a-d2b336c4d4c4 /10.13.90.3   consumer-63
error.foo.bar                    0          8               1125            1117            consumer-63-5b0fd4f0-5289-490f-8c6a-d2b336c4d4c4 /10.13.90.3   consumer-63
error.foo.bar                    27         9               1127            1118            consumer-63-5b0fd4f0-5289-490f-8c6a-d2b336c4d4c4 /10.13.90.3   consumer-63
error.foo.bar                    19         9               1127            1118            consumer-63-5b0fd4f0-5289-490f-8c6a-d2b336c4d4c4 /10.13.90.3   consumer-63
error.foo.bar                    37         8               1126            1118            consumer-63-5b0fd4f0-5289-490f-8c6a-d2b336c4d4c4 /10.13.90.3   consumer-63

etc
```

In response to the comment from StuartLC, I don't think this is a problem with the consumer not keeping up with the rate of ingress. I say this because the current offset and latest offset are remaining static (they've not changed since yesterday).  Also, starting additional consumer instances is not affecting the lag.  The topic consumers are rebalanced to show that there is an additional consumer connected, but the lag remains the same.

Comment: Seemingly `consumer-63` is either not keeping up with the rate of ingress, or is perhaps not committing its offsets frequently. If it's the former, then consider additional consumer processes for the consumer group `error.foo.bar`, and if it's the latter, adjust the various [consumer configs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs) to either commit more frequently, or to auto commit.

Comment: @StuartLC I've updated the question: pretty sure its NOT a problem with the consumers not keeping up.

Comment: "It seems that new messages can be posted to the topic and will be picked up by members of the consumer group, yet the lag will remain" Then the consumer does not seem to commit offsets.  Are you sure the lag stayed constant while the latest offset increased by one?  The lag should either become 0 (new commit) or increase by 1 (no commit).